# Query that runs cannot be saved as a view

Tags: sql

SQL Server 2008

I have a query with several local variables that does some easy math in the result set.  When I copy and paste the query to try to save it as a view, it fails telling me there's incorrect syntax.  (in this case it's near the declare statement of the variables.)  If needed I'll post the query, just wondering if there's a reason for this to work one way and not the other.

```
declare @totalpop float,
@totalMales float,
@totalFemales float,
@percentMales float,
@percentFemales float;
select @totalmales=sum(case when sex='m' then 1 else 0 end),
@totalfemales = sum(case when sex='f' then 1 else 0 end),
@totalpop=count(*)

from tblVisits
select @percentmales = round(100 * @totalmales/@totalpop,2),
@percentFemales = round(100*@totalfemales/@totalpop,2)

select @totalmales,@percentmales,@totalfemales, @percentfemales, @totalpop
```

Comment: Please give more information about your question. Can you copy paste the query you are using?

Comment: Also: which DBMS is this for?

Comment: Doing a quick search, I found this post:  http://bytes.com/topic/sql-server/answers/808528-anyway-declare-use-variables-view.    An answerer stated that you cannot use variables in a view, but did suggest looking at a table valued function.  Another search on MSDN brought up these:  http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Search/en-us?query=table+valued+function

Comment: Just to be clear . . . you cannot use local variables in the definition of a view.  Perhaps what you want is a stored procedure that returns the rows.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need any of the declared variables, you can do this in plain-old sql with a nested select:

```
SELECT totalmales, round(1e2*totalmales/totalpop, 2) percentmales,
       totalfemales, round(1e2*totalfemales/totalpop, 2) percentfemales,
       totalpop
FROM (SELECT sum(case when sex='m' then 1 else 0 end) totalmales,
             sum(case when sex='f' then 1 else 0 end) totalfemales,
             count(*) totalpop
      FROM tblVisits) innerquery
```

Which should be usable on most any database that supports views and subselects (which is basically all of them.

Comment: Despite having lots of upvotes, the original version of this answer will produce 0 for both percentages (or 0 and 1 if everyone is of the same sex), because it does integer division in the outer query. I'm correcting it to work correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use variables inside views. You can, however, transforms it in a SP (Stored procedure) or table-based function.

Edit: Or do what TokenMacGuy told you :P.

Answer (score 0):

You are using SQL Server 2008, so another way to do this is with PIVOT:

```
  create view V as 
  select
    m as totalmales,
    round(1e2*m/(m+f),2) as pctmales,
    f as totalfemales,
    round(1e2*f/(m+f),2) as pctfemales,
    m+f as totalpop
  from tblVisits as T
  pivot (count(sex) for sex in ([m],[f])) as P;
```

If you do this, be sure to keep the 1e2 or use 100.0 instead of 100 inside the round() expression. Otherwise, the divisions m/(m+f) and f/(m+f) will be integer divisions and both yield zero.